# How can I pass user real name as a contextual filter in views

Tags: views, users

I am trying to simply provide a view of author content by passing a contextual link for the author ID to provide a URL with the author's name as selected with the [Real Name](https://drupal.org/project/realname) module.

For instance: "/sitename/content-type/realname".

When I set up the filters, the only way I can get it to work is by providing the user name, not the real name as set by the real name module. I would like to keep the login name private, and use the real name as assigned.

Has anyone had any success doing this?

Answer (score 1):

If the real name is stored in one field in your user, you can set up a relationship with the user and then point to that in the contextual filter, eg, here I just created a "real name" text field in the user and then did this:

[image]

and then for nice looking urls, did this in the filter:

[image]

so I can go to

`www.example.com/by-real-name/this-real-name`

or

`www.example.com/by-real-name/that-real-name`

It's really up to you re: case transformation, but two real caveats:  you have to make sure real names are unique AND it gets really squirrelly if and when special characters are in the real name field.

Comment: Thank you for the great suggestions.  I don't currently have the real name field anywhere other than Profile 2, but was able to add author profile as a relationship after adding author as a relationship. This exposed the name field I had set up to be used for real name with contextual filters.  I was never able to get the URL to convert spaces to dashes unfortunately. When I enter the /content/real name, it still displays /content/real%20name. Perhaps I am misunderstanding what this is supposed to accomplish?

Comment: I am not sure how or where you are creating the links, but the space/dash stuff just allows you to use dashes in the url that Views will then convert internally to spaces to then match to the field.  So for example if you were to create a link in a block or other content displayed on the User's profile, you could create a friendly link using the contents of that real name field by converting those spaces to dashes.  But, realize, if a person has a dash in his/her name, it will be converted to a space and then the match won't work.